# Question about including files with require_once

Tags: php, require-once

I have downloaded this [API](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PHP_SOAP_SDK.tar.gz).

If you go to lib/Paypal/Profile/Handler/Array.php you will find this line:

```
require_once 'PayPal.php';
```

Since the PayPal.php file is in the lib/ folder, I expected something like this:

```
require_once '../../../../PayPal.php'
```

So...where is set what is the "root" folder of the API?

**NOTE:** my question has a reason: I'm trying to know why I'm getting an error like this:

> Warning:
>   require_once(PayPal.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /home/me/app1/plugins/mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/Profile/Handler/Array.php
>   on line 9

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the built-in installer (`/install.php`), it adds code to set the `include_path` here:

```
install.php[130-135]

$code = "<?php\n" .
    "//*******************************************\n" .
    "// AUTO-GENERATED include for PayPal PHP SDK\n" .
    "// Created by install.php on $stamp\n" .
    "//*******************************************\n\n" .
    "set_include_path('$sdk_dir' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '" . $libdir . "' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());\n";
```

Which is why the `README.html` file tells you to run the included installer in order to use the samples.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find this:

[Set Include Path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has what's called an [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) that specifies where it defaults to looking for files to include/require.  You can set it in your php.ini or in your code using [set_include_path()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the Array.php file is itself included by another file, running from somewhere else (probably the root).

When you include (or require) another php-file, it will execute with the same path as the script that included it (which may intern be included by, and thus executed in the path of, yet another script).